# Will read function automatically convert binary pattern?

Tags: c, unix, io

For the following code, why doesn't read function change y? I am writing this code because my professor told us in class that write function will actually write in binary pattern, but when we do a read it will automatically do the conversion. He used

```
read( fd, (char *)&x, 4 );
```

in class as an example, and said that read will give x 10 back, but i don't think read actually change x based on the output of following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
    int fd;
    fd = open( "lowlevelio.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666 );
    int x = 10, y = 3;
    write( fd, (char *)&x, 4 );     
    read( fd, (char *)&y, 4 );
    printf( "%d\n", y );
    close( fd );
}
```

I wonder why read function does not change y to 10?

Comment: After writing, you need to seek back to the beginning of the file so you can read what you just wrote.  Try adding the line `lseek(fd, 0L, 0)` between the `read` and `write` calls.

Comment: Also, I suggest `write( fd, (char *)&x, sizeof(int) )` and `read( fd, (char *)&y, sizeof(int) )`.

Comment: Given that `read()` and `write()` take `void*`s as the pointer-argument, the cast to `char*` is somewhat odd.

Comment: Also, so you know, whatever your professor said (or you thought you heard) about "writing in binary pattern, but read automatically doing a conversion" is confused. `write` always writes raw binary, and that's what `read` reads.

Comment: You have no moral right to expect a system call to do what you hope if you don't check whether it's trying to tell you it failed.

Comment: What Paul is saying is that if you had checked `read`'s return value, you would have discovered that it returned 0 (indicating end-of-file), rather than the 4 bytes you expected.

Comment: Oh, yeah right, I didn't think of that, thanks.